# How to change text in html element under an element using JS

Tags: javascript, html, element, slideshow

**Full Code at Last/end**

I have been working on a project,
So for landing page I wanna make a hero i.e. fade in and out slideshow using JavaScript.

BRIEF:

What I want:- 
I have set a variable to get a random number between 1 and 3, so after depending upon the random number, the image of hero, the quote inside the hero and author name would change using Js!

Problem:-

```
        <div class="hero-1" >
            <img class="hero-img-1" id="slideshow_background" alt="slideshow photo" src="images/hero-1.jpg"  >
                <h2 id="quote_h2" >
                    <span class="quotation" >&#8220;</span> 
                        Don't worry about people stealing your design work.
                        Worry about the day they stop.
                    <span class="quotation" >&#8221;</span>
                </h2>
            <span class="author" >
                <h4 id="author_h4" >–Sohel Shekh</h4>
            </span>
        </div>
```

I want to change the text of quote depending upon the random number (i.e. 1-3)

But as the span element is there, which is for "
So if I

```
quote_txt.innerHTML = "New Quote";
```

It removes / cancels the `<span>` element which contains the **"** quotation marks!

What should I do now so that it only changes the actual text not the `<span>` present inside the `<h3>`??????

Please answer if anybody finds solution:

Full HTML Code:

```js
var slideshow_timing = 4000;
var quote_txt = document.getElementById("quote_h2");
var author_name = document.getElementById("author_h4");
var starting_Status = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
var slideshow_Background = document.getElementById("slideshow_background");

if (starting_Status == 1) {
  slideshow_Background.src = "images/hero-1.jpg";
} else {
  alert("t")
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" , initial-scale="1.0" user-scalable="no" />
  <title>Sohel Editz : Home</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=PT+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700&display=swap">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bellota:ital,wght@1,700&display=swap">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slick-theme.css">

  <style type="text/css">
    * {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      background-color: #fff;
      font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
      ;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <!-- Main div element for all the page elements -->
  <div class="main_Top">
    <div class="nav" id="nav">
      <img class="nav-cont nav-menu" alt="menu" src="images/menu.svg" id="menu" onclick="menuOpt()">
      <!-- <img class="nav-img" alt="logo" src="images/logo.png" id="logo" > -->
      <h2 class="nav-cont nav-logo">Sohel Editz</h2>
      <img class="nav-cont nav-account" alt="account" src="images/account.svg" id="account" onclick="accountOpt()">
    </div>
    <div class="navbar" id="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="applyLogo.html">Apply for logo</a></li>
        <li><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="account-bar" id="account-bar">
      <img id="profile_img" src="images/defaultProfileImg.svg">
      <i class="fa fa-edit" id="edit_pencil"></i>
      <div id="details" class="details">
        <h2 id="user_name">Example Name</h2>
        <h5 id="useremail">someone@example.com</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Span element for reserving space-->
    <div class="headerSpace">
    </div>
    <div class="hero">
      <!-- Hero 1 -->
      <div class="hero-1">
        <img class="hero-img-1" id="slideshow_background" alt="slideshow photo" src="images/hero-1.jpg">
        <h2 id="quote_h2">
          <span class="quotation">&#8220;</span> Don't worry about people stealing your design work. Worry about the day they stop.
          <span class="quotation">&#8221;</span>
        </h2>
        <span class="author">
     <h4 id="author_h4" >–Sohel Shekh</h4>
    </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>

  </div>
</body>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
<script src="js/slick.min.js"></script>


</html>
```

Comment: The easiest solution is to put another span around the quotation text, and change that element's text.

Comment: You could always add a ::before and ::after in CSS with the quotation, example: #quote_h2::before, #quote_h2::after { content: "&#8220;";}. Otherwise you could make a third span as Barmar says and only change that one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the problem you have with using `.innerHTML` is that it will clear the element. It doesn't matter what's inside it, it will be overwritten with what you set it to.

In your case, you have a couple of options:

- Move your text into a container so you can select it and update it
- After you get your `h2` element, find the exact Text Node you want to update and use `.replaceWith`

Example with `replaceWith`:

```js
const h2Quote = document.getElementById('quote_h2');
// Find the Text Node you want to update, in this case, index 2
h2Quote.childNodes[2].replaceWith('Test');
```

```html
<h2 id="quote_h2">
  <span class="quotation">&#8220;</span>
  Don't worry about people stealing your design work. Worry about the day they  stop.
  <span class="quotation">&#8221;</span>
</h2>
```

Comment: Yes, I got your both methods and I got it because I was also thinking for the same!!

Answer (score 0):

The key thing is to keep in a variable the related `<span>` element which represents the quote.

I think the following can work for you:

```js
const quotation = '<span class="quotation">&#8220;</span>';
const quote_txt = document.getElementById('quote_h2');

const quote = 'New Quote';
quote_txt.innerHTML = `${quotation}${quote}${quotation}`;
// or: quote_txt.innerHTML = quotation + quote + quotation;
```

```html
<h2 id="quote_h2" >
    <span class="quotation" >&#8220;</span> 
        Don't worry about people stealing your design work.
        Worry about the day they stop.
    <span class="quotation" >&#8221;</span>
</h2>
```

I hope that helps!